# Mutation of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, methods

For some reason I can't get below code working as expected.

I have declared variable dna with random 15 elements, each of its elements is random letter from array dnaBases.

Mutate function should create new (similar array) with random 15 elements, but elements from first array must not repeat. Instead, they should be replaced by the remaining three elements in dnaBases array.

Problem in my code is that sometimes letters are repeating even though in previous cases the did not.

```
const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
var dna = []
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  dna.push(dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)])
}

function mutate() {
  console.log(dna) // to check newly generated dna array
  var tmp = []
  var newDnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
  for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    tmp.push(newDnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
  }

  console.log(tmp) // to check newly generated tmp array

  for (var k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      if (tmp[k] === dna[k]) {
        var x = newDnaBases.splice(tmp[k], 1);
        tmp[k] = newDnaBases[randomIndex];
        newDnaBases.push(x.toString());
      }
  }
  console.log(tmp) // to see how tmp has changed after for loop
  console.log(newDnaBases) // to check if newDnaBases is not corrupted
}

mutate()
```

I am new in Javascript and I can't see the problem at first glance.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in js , array methods like *split, slice ou reduce*, are used to return a "clone" of the array variable with the changes that the method applies.
like

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a.filter(i => {
      if (i === 2) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
})
b[0] === 2 // true
a[2] === 3 // true
```

so the in your code:

```
const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
var dna = []
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  dna.push(dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)])
}

function mutate() {
  console.log(dna) 
  var tmp = []
  var newDnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
  for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    tmp.push(newDnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
  }

  console.log(tmp) // to check newly generated tmp array

  for (var k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      if (tmp[k] === dna[k]) {
        var x = newDnaBases.filter(i=> i!== tmp[k]) //returns the array without the repeated item, without altering the original variable
        tmp[k] = x[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
      }
  }
  console.log(tmp)
  console.log(newDnaBases) 
}

mutate()
```

Comment: Thanks, I absolutely forgot about filter method.

Comment: you are welcome, and btw, if you are working white large quantities of data (real dna values), i would recommend you to use, `"array Variable".forEach((value,index,orgArray)=>{/* function here*/})`, because it works asynchronous, that way your code would be more optimized